# where to store XML files

Tags: android

I'm storing app data in a few XML files.  Should I put these XML files in the 'res' folder? Is there anything special I need to do besides just using something like:

```
XmlPullParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.myXMLfile);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to store these file in the assets folder. Use the following code to read file form the assets folder:

```
getResources().getAssets().open(fileName);
```

Comment: Res folder is used to store android project specific files like layout, images, etc. It is always good to store application specific file's in a separate folder.

Answer (score 1):

No, nothing, as long as these are completely static in nature.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an app data & if you feel to have lightweight app then try to store in the internal memory ,make use of it & get benefited.